# Is it safe to link a gcc excutable with a Visual C++ library?

Tags: c++, mingw, oracle-call-interface, mingw32

How safe is linking MinGW excutable with a library that was compiled by Visual C++.

Something like what is explained here.
http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2011/12/09/oci-mingw/

TL; DR  "... because OCI is a C library, we can take the “official” OCI import library for VC++, `oci.lib`, rename it to `libclntsh.a`, and we’ve got OCI for MinGW"

Is this an accident waiting to happen? What could go wrong?

Comment: Name mangling incompatibilities, alignment variance between implementations, all kinds of things spell potential doom.

Comment: C has an ABI. Connecting through a C API is safe. C++ does not on Windows.

Comment: I'm just quite surprised that the `ld` linker even deals with Microsoft's object file and library formats. Since this is apparently an import library for a DLL using a C interface, things will probably work fine - MinGW needs to work with DLLs in general to be at all useful on Windows, so it works well with DLL imports. The main possible problem I think would be the general issue of allocating/freeing memory across runtime libraries. But I suspect that OCI.dll is designed to avoid this (as that would be a problem with VC builds as well).

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

AFAIK, there is nothing to stop the glibc and msvcrt co-existing in the same process on Windows - the same global function search that occurs on Linux doesn't occur on windows (every dynamic import knows which DLL it comes from - functions are not merged in a single namespace).

However there may be problems with particular libraries. If the library specifies for example that "the function returns a pointer, which should be freed with `free()` when done", you need to free it with the **correct** free, i.e. the one corresponding to the `malloc()` it was allocated with. Likewise if the function states "parameter is a buffer which will be freed with `free()` by the function" then it must be allocated with the corresponding `malloc()`. Similar issues apply where `realloc()` may be used.

This issue also occurs for example when using DLLs compiled against differing versions of MSVCRT e.g. MSVCRT20.dll vs. MSVCRT40.dll.

That's why windows libraries always state how memory should be allocated. see for example CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree, LocalAlloc/LocalFree, HeapAlloc/HeapFree. Documentation may state "When no longer needed the buffere must be freed with CoTaskMemFree". Or they may supply their own free/alloc pairs e.g. "When no longer needed the returned buffer must be freed with SuperLibraryFreeBuffer" (which internally may simply delegate to the CRT `free`, but at least it will be the correct version of free).

This is because windows is and always has been a multi-language platform where libraries can be written in languages other than C. Today we may be used to the idea that Lisp, Pascal, etc are a layer on top of the C runtime, - most programmers probably assume that even when it isn't true as in the case of Pascal -  but it wasn't always the way: Pascal was in common use on DEC computers for two years before C was invented, and the Windows heritage as everyone knows has a lot in common with DEC. Early versions of Windows were written largly in assembler and ... there is a reason for that "pascal" calling convention in the Windows 3 headers you know...

Comment: You raise improtant ideas but someone has downvoted your answer I wish they provided the reason why. I am not sufficiently knowledgable in this area to tell if your are correct or offbase

Comment: Keep in mind that the problem of allocating & freeing memory from different runtime libraries is a problem that can occur even if all modules are compiled with VC (even the same version).  So linking a MinGW application with a VC library (especially a DLL) doesn't really add much to this mix.  Also, remember that as far as the C runtime is concerned, MinGW doesn't use glibc (or if it does, only a very small part). The bulk of the MinGW C runtime is the msvcrt.dll that is shipped as part of Windows. I'm not sure what effect the C++ runtime has on compatibility.